# Is there any method or methods for clone existing OS to docker container for simulating digital twin?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, operating-system, simulation

In our example there is OS that runs a lot of different programs (also include some GUI programs) our goal is use method or methods for clone exiting OS to docker container and create digital twin of existing OS. All programs must be operational and we can start testing and see  how our twin mimicking of real system.

- Tried copying files and software to docker container which works in same cases but I wonder for methods for fully automated way.
- Tried Running X11 applications with Docker for solve GUI problem.
- **These two ways works for majority of cases but need for more robust and automated method/s**
- **GUI part is not must but will be nice**.

Comment: Docker is for running a single process in isolation on top of the host OS. A docker image does not contain an OS. It sounds like a VM would be more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @HansKilian, VM was one of solutions of course, but imagine simulating a local network with 50 OS. It will also manual, uses a lot of resource. Also it was my bad for mentioning GUI parts in question that leads to VM.

Comment: One of the things that also struck me is that you say each OS runs a lot of different programs. A Docker container usually only runs a single program.